# Why my iPhone app runs in fullscreen on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode6

I have an iPhone app which works fine on iPhone 5 and 4s, when i run it on iPad2 i am expecting it to run in small window with 2x resolution but instead it runs fullscreen messing up all the layouts, apple has rejected my app and i need a fix.

I have created this app as iPhone only and built on Xcode 6 with ios8.0 sdk,
Please help
thanks

Comment: iPhone only but rejected for not resizing correctly on iPad?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @RameezHussain please check the answer at the bottom, i solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so finally deleted the xib file which i was using as launch screen and used the default images instead that solved the issue for me now , app runs in 2x mode on iPad with launch screen.

Comment: What's the point of providing that elegant solution when most developers can't take advantage of it? Anyway, thanks for posting the solution.

Comment: @RameezHussain question was mine , not universal so solution will be of that kind only and question wasn't intentionally created , thanks for comment anyways, also there is no code involved so can't really help

Answer (score 3):

If you set a launch screen for your app, it will be fullscreen on iPad.

In Xcode, select your app target, then select `General` tab, scroll to `App Icons and Launch Images`, checkout the `Launch Screen File`.

Comment: so is there any solution using which i can have launch screen and app doesn't run fullscreen ?

Comment: @vishal not that I know of. I think it's better this way. :)

Comment: I can't keep it fullscreen on iPad as its rejected by apple but i want the launch screen too.